# Probability question with two conditions

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

> New car registrationsplates contain two letters followed by two numerals followed by two more letters. Letters and numbers may be repeated. Which expression gives the number of car registration plates that start and finish with the SAME letter?

Example number plate would be this:

MA * 12 * TH

So it should start with letter x, and end with x.

I lack the intuition to be able to begin solving this problem. Can someone show me how ?

Answer (score 4):

You have $26$ choices for the first letter, $26$ for the second, $10$ choices for the first digit, $10$ choices for the second digit, and $26$ choices for the third letter.

The fourth letter, however, has to be the same as the first letter, so you only have $1$ choice there. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the letter to be repeated in $26$ ways.

You can choose the other two letters in $26\times26$ ways

You can choose the numerals in $10\times10 $ ways assuming $0$ is allowed

Multiply these together

Answer (score 1):

If the first and last letters are the same, then there are 26 ways this can happen. A****A, B****B etc. For each of these 26 ways there are different combinations possible for the middle four alphanumerics. Let the number of combinations for middle four be x. Then, we know 26*x is the answer we are looking for.

Using similar arguments, we find the number of possible ways to fill each position in the middle four and then multiply the possibilities to get all the possible combinations where repetition is allowed. ie. x = 26*10*10*26.

Hence, the total number of combinations with starting and ending letter the same will be 26*10*10*26*26.

Answer (score 0):

$28\cdot 28\cdot 28\cdot 10\cdot 10$ ways.
Fill in the first and last entry by $28$ ways. The rest is trivial.